# TinyMCE code not working

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce

I have the following code which is not working properly:

```
 tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea#notice_template",
content_css : '<?php echo($method->baseURL()); ?>/Theme/master_custom.css?' + new Date().getTime(),
theme: "modern",
fontsize_formats: "2pt 4pt 6pt 8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 20pt 22pt 24pt 26pt 28pt 30pt 32pt 34pt 36pt",
height: 300
plugins: [
     "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
     "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
     "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor filemanager"
     ],
```

Any help be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put a  comma (",") after the attribute `"height:300"`

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#notice_template",
    content_css : '<?php echo($method->baseURL()); ?>/Theme/master_custom.css?' + new Date().getTime(),
    theme: "modern",
    fontsize_formats: "2pt 4pt 6pt 8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 20pt 22pt 24pt 26pt 28pt 30pt 32pt 34pt 36pt",
    height: 300,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
        "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor filemanager"
    ],
```